# Set the thickness of Android Circle Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-view, android-theme, android-styles, android-progressbar

I find the default Android progress bar very thick when large, is there anyway to make the bar thinner in the circular indetermindate.

I dont want to use a custom drawable if possible. It always slows things down and gives a two two gradient I dont like

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without using custom drawables. As an alternative, you can use a third-party library, such as [CircularProgressView](https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView), to create a customizable Material progress indicator.